# Level 3 metisMenu item not expanding back to active selection

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following bootstrap navigation sidebar with metisMenu jquery library:

```
<div id="Sidebar" class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="/Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='#'>
                    <i class='fa fa-calendar fa-fw'></i> Diary<span class='glyphicon arrow'></span>
                </a>
                <ul class='nav nav-second-level'>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/Diary/Index?diaryModeId=1">My Actions</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='#'>
                    <i class='fa fa-pie-chart fa-fw'></i> MI<span class='glyphicon arrow'></span>
                </a>
                <ul class='nav nav-second-level'>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/MI/EntityStatus">Entity Status</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='#'>
                    <i class='fa fa-cogs fa-fw'></i> Administration<span class='glyphicon arrow'></span>
                </a>
                <ul class='nav nav-second-level'>

                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>
                            Question Admin<span class='fa plus-minus'></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class='nav nav-third-level'>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/Rule/Index">Business Rules</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/Question/Index">Question Bank</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'>
                            User Admin<span class='fa plus-minus'></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class='nav nav-third-level'>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/User/Index">Users</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/Team/Index">Teams</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I run the following code on refresh:

```
$(function () {

    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();

});
```

Level 1 and level 2 selection works fine with the menu collapsing then re-selecting selected menu option. When I select a level 3 item (such as Question Bank) the menu collapses but then does not re-select. Is there something else I need to do? Is my html mark up correct?

Comment: I'm having the same problem too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a third level menu item (or any level menu item), you need to make sure that all its ancestor `li` items have `class="active"`.